# Qt - how to initialize some actions from inside of an application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, udp, qt4

I'm writing simple UDP chat in Qt. There is QUDPSocket class providing listening and sending messages. Problem is it is controlled by signals so I must call app.exec() otherwise listening will not emit any signal. This is my main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "receiver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
int port = 5555;
Receiver rec;
rec.startListening(port);
for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    QByteArray ba;
    ba = "Hello";
    rec.send(ba, QHostAddress::LocalHost, port);
    ba = rec.getLastMsg();
    QTextStream(stdout) << i << ":" << ba.data() << endl;
}

return app.exec();
}
```

Well problem is the QUDPSocket start to work after app.exec() is called. It's mad. Is there a way provided by Qt to handle this without using another thread for sending UDP packets?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App.exec() starts the main loop and doesn't prevent you from sending packets in the same thread at all.  You just need to send them based on events - like user pressing enter key or a timer if you're just testing. This is how event based programming works in basically all toolkits out there.

Comment: But how can I add code do the app.exec() infinity loop which will be started with GUI refresh functions again and again? Somethink like (if exists): app.addFunctionToLoop(function); and then app.exec();

Comment: As I said,  you can use timers, see e.g. [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/timers.html)